# Generic recursive function in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to write generic recursive function like below

```
function withChildren<
  T extends {
    id?: string;
    parentId?: string;
  },
  TWithChild extends T & {
    children: TWithChild[];
  }
>(parentItem: T, items: T[]): TWithChild {
  const children = items.filter((ba) => ba.parentId === parentItem.id);

  return {
    ...parentItem,
    children: children.map((child) => withChildren(child, items)),
  };
}
```

but typescript throw an error

> Type 'T & { children: (T extends BusinessAreaWithAccess ?
> BusinessAreaWithChildrenAndAccess : BusinessAreaWithChildren)[]; }' is
> not assignable to type 'T extends BusinessAreaWithAccess ?
> BusinessAreaWithChildrenAndAccess : BusinessAreaWithChildren'

i have search for the error, but still not found any solution

Comment: Please paste error-messages into the question, rather than screenshotting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TWithChild` *extends* `T & ...`, meaning if used as explicit type parameter it can union e.g. `{a: 1}`, you don't know its exact type, so you can't instantiate it.
Define it as a known limited generic type, then it'll work

```
type TWithChild<T> = T & {children: TWithChild<T>[]}

function withChildren<
  T extends {
    id?: string;
    parentId?: string;
  }
>(parentItem: T, items: T[]): TWithChild<T> {
  const children = items.filter((ba) => ba.parentId === parentItem.id);

  return {
    ...parentItem,
    children: children.map((child) => withChildren(child, items)),
  };
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg6gS2ACwMLIQGwCYB4YB8UAvLFAGRQDeAxhjgE4QB2AXLIiulnoQNoBdAL4AoEQDMArsxrAEAe2ZQA7kjT1sTZrhFQyEAB7AW2AM7VdeqAmwB%20dqeAMEzAOYBuS3rABDLcABJOwcnFw9LUQIACl9-AOMAW3YYABprRNNkwQBKZM51HnwiKksaRUcoOh4tEnSIBNMAOnEsYwYoqIAjH2ySIm7G2JZA7BJiUiHmQMTGm2zPSyZgSQYlEqsoRq3J6fqUr0qNLXYqxhZGhJ8wDtPsXuIiVS4jlijbtKR602zs-b0hTxCIA)